How do I install lfr in python and find compatible version of dependences?
I have a code (which is not mine) and I need to run it (I have a short time and it's really important to run it as soos as possible). This code uses lfr this way:
from lfr import LFR_benchmark_graph
My problem is that I can't install lfr. I deleted every version of python I had and even deleted pycharm. Then I followed these steps: installed python 3.8.10 (Comments in the code suggested), created a virtual environment and updated pip then ran the command "pip install lfr".
After 7 hours, download stopped (while trying to find the compatible numpy version), and ResolutionTooDeep error poped up:
"pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.ResolutionTooDeep: 2000000"
Can anyone guide me through installing lfr?
I searched and found that networkX has LFR_benchmark_graph as well. Are these the same? if yes, then can I just replace networkX with lfr in "from lfr import LFR_benchmark_graph"?
I installed lfr without dependencies but it didn't work.
Also I found a dependences.txt file for lfr in github and installed dependences, but when I tried to install lfr I got this error:
ERROR: Packages installed from PyPI cannot depend on packages which are not also hosted on PyPI.
lfr depends on dafd@ /home/krishna/CIDAR/DAFD
